# Service object not updating from controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I have a directive (shippingInformation) that contains a customers shipping information.  This information is used outside of the directive, and on multiple screens, so I want to retain the data in a service until it is finally submitted to the server.  However, the code below always shows checkoutData.shipping as an empty object.

Important: I need the binding to work 2 ways.  So ng-model on my form should update the value in the service when the user changes information.

Directive

```
(function () {
    angular.module('checkoutApp').directive('shippingInformation', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/Checkout/ShippingInformation/shippingInformation.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $log, shippingInformationService, checkoutData) {
                $scope.shipping = checkoutData.shipping;
                shippingInformationService.getDefault()
                    .then(function (success) {
                        $scope.shipping = success.data;
                        $log.debug(checkoutData.shipping);  // <-- this is null
                    }, function (error) {
                        $log.error(error);
                    });
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Service

```
(function() {
    angular.module('checkoutApp').factory('checkoutData', function() {
        var data = {
            shipping: {},
        };
        return {
            shipping: data.shipping
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: You need to make $scope.shipping an object with a shipping property on it.  Otherwise you are just copying the value to the scope and when it is being updated, it isn't updating the underlying service object.  Try $scope.checkoutData = checkoutData, and then bind to the shipping property on that.

Comment: shipping is an object, which is why I thought this would work.. but you're right that setting $scope.checkoutData = checkoutData; is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get this to work with 2 way data-binding I had to reference checkoutData from my controller and checkoutData.shipping.field from my template.

Controller:

PREVIOUS: `$scope.shipping = checkoutData.shipping`

CORRECTED: `$scope.checkoutData = checkoutData`

HTML changed:

PREVIOUS: `ng-model='shipping.lastName'`

CORRECTED: `ng-model='checkoutData.shipping.lastName'`

Not sure if there's a cleaner way but this is all I could get to work with 2-way binding.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('checkoutApp').directive('shippingInformation', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'Scripts/Checkout/ShippingInformation/shippingInformation.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $log, shippingInformationService, checkoutData) {
                $scope.checkoutData = checkoutData; <!-- set scope to the service rather then the object contained within
                shippingInformationService.getDefault()
                    .then(function (success) {
                        checkoutData.shipping = success.data; <!-- set the value in the service
                    }, function (error) {
                        $log.error(error);
                    });
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use simple syntax

```
app.factory("factoryname", function() {
    var data = null;
    return {
        setData: function(someData) {
            data = someData;
        },
        getData: function() {
            return data;
        }
    }
});
```

and in controller

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, shared) {
    $scope.data = shared.getData();
});
```

Comment: but would this binding work 2 ways?  that's what I need on this form

Comment: Yes . in controller whereever you will call factory function, you will pass $scope.<variablename> ..and to multiple screens also you can pass on data. and finally submit to server via service.

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting the shipping variable inside your factory. You could employ getters/setters to accomplish this:

**Factory**

```
(function() {
    angular.module('checkoutApp').factory('checkoutData', function() {
        var data = {
            shipping: {},
        };
        return {
            getShipping: function () {
              return data.shipping;
            },
            setShipping: function (obj) {
              data.shipping = obj;
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

**Controller**

```
.then(function (success) {
  $scope.shipping = success.data;
  checkoutData.setShipping($scope.shipping);
  $log.debug(checkoutData.shipping);
```